prevent javaScript from parsing html
var text = "<script></script>";
var div = getElementById("wrap");
div.innerHTML = text;

how can I prevent JavaScript from parsing html tags? this code returns blank because it displays as a script tag. I want to display as text only to prevent XSS.

javascript is NOT parsing anything in this code
